# Get Unique Value from List of Objects in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to get the list of objects in a python script via For loop like below:

```
for org in Details:
    file.write("Organization Name : %s \n" % (org.orgName))
    file.write("Name : %s \n" % (org.repoName))
    file.write(" URL : %s \n" % (org.repoURL))
```

The output comes out to be like:

```
Organization Name : A
Name : B
URL : C 

Organization Name : A
Name : B

Organization Name : D
Name : E
URL : F 

Organization Name : D
Name : E
URL : F 

Organization Name : D
Name : E
URL : F
```

How do I make sure that only unique values are printed?  The output which I am expecting:

```
Organization Name : A
Name : B
URL : C 

Organization Name : D
Name : E
URL : F
```

Answer (score 0):

dont write in the file immediately. Inside the loop, store the details in a datastructure, a set of toples (orgname,name,url) or if one of your detail is unique use a dictionary and use for example the organization name as key and a tople(name,url) as the value.

```
dictionnary = dict()
for org in Details:
    dictionnary[org.orgName] = [org.repoName,org.repoURL]

for key in dict.Keys():
    file.write("Organization Name : %s \n" % (key))
    file.write("Name : %s \n" % (dictionnary[key][0]))
    file.write(" URL : %s \n" % (dictionnary[key][1]))
```

Then go thourgh all the elements of the dictionnary and write inside your file like you did.

2nd solution which I'm not sure would work depending on what's inside Details.
Change nothing in your code except just before the for loop, write

```
Details=set(Details)
for org in Details:
    file.write("Organization Name : %s \n" % (org.orgName))
    file.write("Name : %s \n" % (org.repoName))
    file.write(" URL : %s \n" % (org.repoURL))
```

Reminder : a set is a list of unsorted values with no duplicates